# How to understand zlib-compressed query profiles of Apache Impala

Tags: python, hadoop, cloudera, impala, impyla

Impala currently saves query profile logs at /var/log/impala/profiles , per line in the format

```
<Epoch-Timestamp> <QueryID> <zlib-compressed-data>
```

As mentioned in their document at https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_logging.html

***"To save space, those query profiles are now stored in zlib-compressed files in /var/log/impala/profiles."***

I want to decode/decompress the zlib-compressed data in human readable format using some utility instead of Web UI exposed at 25000.

From the logs and documentation I have been able to figure out that the zlib-compressed data has been encoded using base64.
I was able to write a python code to decompress the zlib-compression,

```
import base64
import datetime
import zlib

profile_data = "1587093056765 c94ef1f2e35015a2:feb1867165d545a7 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"

pdata = profile_data.split(" ")

ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(pdata[0]) / 1000.0).isoformat()
queryID = pdata[1]

encodedData = base64.b64decode(pdata[2])
zlib_data = zlib.decompress(encodedData)

print(zlib_data)
```

The above Python utility gives the following output,which has some meaningful information but not complete.

```
b'\x19<\x18,Query (id=c94ef1f2e35015a2:feb1867165d545a7)\x15\x04\x19,\x18\x11InactiveTotalTime\x15\n\x16\x00\x00\x18\tTotalTime\x15\n\x16\x00\x00\x16\x01\x11\x1b\x00\x19\x08\x1b\x00\x00\x18\x07Summary\x15\x00\x19,\x18\x11InactiveTotalTime\x15\n\x16\x00\x00\x18\tTotalTime\x15\n\x16\x00\x00\x16\x01\x11\x1b\x11\x88\x0eConnected User\x04root\x0bCoordinator\x19quickstart.cloudera:22000\x08DDL Type\x0cCREATE_TABLE\nDefault Db\x0bexperiments\x0eDelegated User\x00\x08End Time\x1d2020-04-17 03:10:56.764883000\x0eImpala VersionWimpalad version 2.5.0-cdh5.7.0 RELEASE (build ad3f5adabedf56fe6bd9eea39147c067cc552703)\x0fNetwork Address\x0f127.0.0.1:33152\x1bQuery Options (non default)\x00\x0bQuery State\x08FINISHED\x0cQuery Status\x02OK\nQuery Type\x03DDL\nSession ID!9540492d44759bbf:90f082030ba231ae\x0cSession Type\x07BEESWAX\rSql Statement\x17create table t1 (x int)\nStart Time\x1d2020-04-17 03:10:56.417452000\x04User\x04root\x19\xf8\x11\nSession ID\x0cSession Type\nStart Time\x08End Time\nQuery Type\x0bQuery State\x0cQuery Status\x0eImpala Version\x04User\x0eConnected User\x0eDelegated User\x0fNetwork Address\nDefault Db\rSql Statement\x0bCoordinator\x1bQuery Options (non default)\x08DDL Type\x1b\x00\x19,\x18\x00\x19\x06\x19\x08\x00\x18\x0eQuery Timeline\x19V\x00\xec\x93\xe0U\x98\x9c\xc5\xc8\x02\xae\xda\xcd\xca\x02\xae\xda\xcd\xca\x02\x19X\x0fStart execution\x11Planning finished\x10Request finished\x11First row fetched\x10Unregister query\x00\x00\x18\x0cImpalaServer\x15\x00\x19\\\x18\x12CatalogOpExecTimer\x15\n\x16\xc4\xd1\xba\xe8\x01\x00\x18\x14ClientFetchWaitTimer\x15\n\x16\x96\xbe\x88\x02\x00\x18\x11InactiveTotalTime\x15\n\x16\x00\x00\x18\x17RowMaterializationTimer\x15\n\x16\x00\x00\x18\tTotalTime\x15\n\x16\x00\x00\x16\x01\x11\x1b\x00\x19\x08\x1b\x01\x8a\x008\x12CatalogOpExecTimer\x14ClientFetchWaitTimer\x17RowMaterializationTimer\x00\x00'
```

Any pointers to understand/parse the Impala profile log programmatically would be really appreciable.

Comment: Just a pointer: Impala source on git https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/be/src/kudu/util/zlib.cc#L76 and try to follow the compression logic.

Comment: But wouldnt it be easier to get whatever details you're looking for through REST from impalad/coordinator that ran a query? https://<impalad_host>:25000/query_profile?query_id=<query_id>

Comment: @mazaneicha while rest is easy but the API ports have been blocked so only have the option to parse the file.

Answer (score 1):

**Upd.** Edited to include source code and some comments.

I guess this is the script that you're looking for (taken from Impala Git [here](https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/lib/python/impala_py_lib/profiles.py)):

```
    import base64
    import datetime
    import zlib
    from thrift.protocol import TCompactProtocol
    from thrift.TSerialization import deserialize
    from RuntimeProfile.ttypes import TRuntimeProfileTree

    def decode_profile_line(line):
      space_separated = line.split(" ")
      if len(space_separated) == 3:
        ts = int(space_separated[0])
        print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000.0).isoformat(), space_separated[1]
        base64_encoded = space_separated[2]
      elif len(space_separated) == 1:
        base64_encoded = space_separated[0]
      else:
        raise Exception("Unexpected line: " + line)
      possibly_compressed = base64.b64decode(base64_encoded)
      # Handle both compressed and uncompressed Thrift profiles
      try:
        thrift = zlib.decompress(possibly_compressed)
      except zlib.error:
        thrift = possibly_compressed

      tree = TRuntimeProfileTree()
      deserialize(tree, thrift, protocol_factory=TCompactProtocol.TCompactProtocolFactory())
      tree.validate()

    return tree

    encoded_line = "timestamp queryid encoded_profile_string"
    decoded_tree = decode_profile_line(encoded_line)
```

Basically, it does the same thing as you did in your snippet, but it also deciphers Thrift-specific encoding afterwards. "thrift" stands for libraries from Apache Thrift itself (more info in Apache Thrift [docs](https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/py) and [Git](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/py)), and RuntimeProfile is Impala's structure definition (you can view it in [Impala Git](https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/common/thrift/RuntimeProfile.thrift)) that contains nodes and summary of script execution:

```
    // A flattened tree of runtime profiles, obtained by an
    // pre-order traversal
    struct TRuntimeProfileTree {
      1: required list<TRuntimeProfileNode> nodes
      2: optional ExecStats.TExecSummary exec_summary
    }
```

Let's look closer at ["deserialize"](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/py/src/TSerialization.py) method in Thrift:

```
    def deserialize(base,
            buf,
            protocol_factory=TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()):
      transport = TTransport.TMemoryBuffer(buf)
      protocol = protocol_factory.getProtocol(transport)
      base.read(protocol)
      return base
```

"base" stands for a tree that will be returned to you, with all of its' nodes and subnodes. So, there are two options to dig from here on:

1. Browse through Impala code; it seems that all of the necessary definitions are stored in this [subfolder](https://github.com/apache/impala/tree/master/common/thrift) of their Git; it's possible to replicate their logic.
2. Write custom "deserialize" and debug output from "protocol_factory.getProtocol(transport)" to define "base" tree (again: it's probably a bit easier to look necessary nodes in Impala source code).

Comment: Please post the script code directly in your answer

Comment: @Vladimir-yurev , Thanks for suggestion, the repository uses 'RuntimeProfile' library which somehow I am unable to find or build. While I am making an effort to find out how can I get 'RuntimeProfile'. If you are familiar with the project your help would be highly appreciable.   https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/53ff6f9bf5ca907f15ec1187eb5d4007d46eb61e/lib/python/impala_py_lib/profiles.py

Comment: Edited original post; hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might help other people coming across this. There's an example script for parsing runtime profile logs in the Apache Impala repository that is a good place to start with building your own tool - https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/bin/parse-thrift-profile.py. It's tied into the Impala development environment - specifically it needs to compile the thrift definitions and generate Python from them, which requires a working development environment. As of writing you can get this working by checking out Impala and setting up part of the environment:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/impala.git
cd impala
. bin/impala-config.sh
./bin/bootstrap_toolchain.py
./buildall.sh -cmake_only -noclean
make thrift-deps
./bin/parse-thrift-profile.py ./impala_profile_log_1.1-1594189561854
```